# При попытке воспроизвести сгенерированный звук более 50сек возникает ошибка

Tags: java, android

Создаю массив и из него воспроизвожу:

```
byte[] buffer = gen_change_wave(10, 20, 50000);
    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, buffer.length, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    audioTrack.play();
```

длительность 50000мс (50 сек)
Если ставлю 40сек, то все работает.

Длинна массива buffer[] = 44100 * 50 сек = 2205000;

Ошибка!

```
E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=4194528
D/MemoryDealer:   AudioTrack (0xf389cbd0, size=4194304)
                                             0: 0xf389cc00 | 0x00000000 | 0x00400000 | F 
                                           size allocated: 0 (0 KB)
E/AudioFlinger: createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
/a.gensnd E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
/a.gensnd E/AudioTrack-JNI: Error -12 initializing AudioTrack
a.gensnd E/android.media.AudioTrack: Error code -20 when initializing AudioTrack.
a.gensnd D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
a.gensnd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                    Process: a.gensnd, PID: 7719
                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: play() called on uninitialized AudioTrack.
                                                        at android.media.AudioTrack.play(AudioTrack.java:1742)
                                                        at a.gensnd.Beeper.generateMiddleBeep(Beeper.java:32)
                                                        at a.gensnd.aMain$1$1.run(aMain.java:43)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Не хватает памяти! Что можно сделать?

Comment: Что за ошибка-то?